# How to set text size in a button in html

Tags: html, button, text, size

Hello I want to have a button on my website and I want to resize the text on my button. How do I do this?

My code is below:

```
<input type="submit" value="HOME" onclick="goHome()" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"/>
```

Comment: Let's try this link, I think it'll help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496949/font-size-for-button-and-link

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" 
       value="HOME" 
       onclick="goHome()" 
       style="font-size : 20px; width: 100%; height: 100px;" />
```

Comment: @user2627595 it's ok welcome , you can also define class for that instead of inline style.

Answer (score 9):

Try this, its working in FF

```
body,
input,
select,
button {
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Belated. If need any fancy button than anyone can try this.

```css
#startStopBtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #dcfbb4;
    background-color: green;
    border: 0.4em solid #d4f7da;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
}
#startStopBtn:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #29a074;
  }
```

```html
<div id="startStopBtn" onclick="startStop()" class=""> Go!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using inline CSS you could set the text size of all your buttons using:

```
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```